# Add a function to ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I would like to add this function

```
ma <- function(x,n=11){filter(x,rep(1/n,n),method = "convolution", sides=2)}
```

` 
to my data:

```
ggplot(data, aes(y=volume, x=time)) +
   geom_line(color= "black", size=0.2, alpha=0.9) +
   theme_classic() +
   ggtitle(" Volume")
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: How to add the function in the plot script

Comment: Can you generate some dummy data or use a standard dataset included in R that is supposed to be appropriate for the plot / function?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any sample data, here's a solution based on some random dummy data:

```
library(ggplot2)

ma <- function(x,n=11){filter(x,rep(1/n,n),method = "convolution", sides=2)}

x <- runif(1000)
data = data.frame(time = x, volume <- ma(x))

ggplot(data, aes(y=volume, x=time)) +
   geom_line(color= "black", size=0.2, alpha=0.9) +
   theme_classic() +
   ggtitle(" Volume")
```